# Wii Remotes Connect and Disconnect from Wii U

Tags: wii-u

When I try to use my Wii Remotes on the Wii U menu and on the Wii channel within the console, the remote will turn on, and immediately turn off. I can see the cursor on the screen. Occassionally, I can hit a button before the remote turns off, but this is very rare. When I actually make it to play a game, the Wii remote will stay on and not turn off, and will function perfectly. There is no interference or battery issues. It does it with all four remotes I own.